# Find if possible a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $v_1 \cdot w = 3$ and $v_2 \cdot w = 6$ and $v_3 \cdot w = 10$. Find, if possible, a vector $u$ so that $u \cdot w = 13$.

I feel that this is an inconsistent system of linear equations to begin with.

Letting $v(1-3)$ and $w = 1$

$$\pmatrix{1 &1 &3\\1 &1 &3\\1 &1 &6} \begin{matrix}\longrightarrow \\{RREF}\end{matrix} \pmatrix{1 &1 &10\\1 &1 &10\\0 &0 &\mathbf 3}$$

The question doesn't ask if those equations are consistent, it asks if I could make something else with it and it still be consistence. What am I missing here?

Comment: What's wrong with $\vec u=\frac {13}3\vec {v_1}$?   Or $\vec u= \vec {v_1}+\vec {v_3}$   Also, I see nothing inconsistent in these equations.

Comment: @lulu how did you come up with those answers?

Comment: In general $(a\vec v)\cdot  \vec u=a(\vec v\cdot \vec u)$.  Thus $\vec u=\frac {13}6\vec {v_2}$ would also work.  For the last one, I just noticed that $3+10=13$.